# How can I get html code created by javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I need to get html code of a web site using c# (web browser or webrequest)  but I have a problem for html code created by javascript.

actually I need View Generated Source of Web Developer plugin (its plugin of firefox)

how can i do it?

edit1: I found a solution using javascript:'' + window.document.body.outerHTML+ ''
but it's not working in IE9

Comment: Please edit your question, instead of adding information in comments. Moreover, you should see those changes in the DOM inspector of Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

in google chrome you can view the source by click right on item and inspect element command fire fox and ie9 has such functionality in another way,In Ie by pressing F12 you can use developer tools and view sources

Answer (score 0):

FireBug is a great plugin for Firefox that allows you to browse the DOM, including HTML generated dynamically by javascript.